# Airplay Screen Mirroring

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, screen, airplay

I want to make an Airplay Server like [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/). I follow the [Unofficial AirPlay Protocol Specification](http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html) and have got the Post/stream request

```
{

authTime = "514438570.684865"; 
channel = 36; 
configTime = "0.005387008190155029"; 
connectTime = "0.07017600536346436"; 
deviceID = 101801960822832; 
deviceInfoTime = "-514438570.664322"; 
fpsInfo =     ( 
            { 
        name = SubS; 
    },
            {
        name = B4En;
    },
            {
        name = EnDp;
    },
            {
        name = IdEn;
    },
            {
        name = IdDp;
    },
            {
        name = EQDp;
    },
            {
        name = QueF;
    },
            {
        name = Sent;
    }
);
latencyMs = 75;
macAddress = "5C:96:9D:B6:58:2E";
param1 = <46504c59 01020100 0000003c 00000000 e1d6ae07 57b41f03 99678724 30ace328 00000010 ed8dc722 55e12dad d1655851 71aeffc5 6a0403ad a8cffc91 75e61d5d d24ae6ab fb2d4949>;
param2 = <84688026 a2e58619 1003511e 3506fc27>;
prepareTime = "0.02281397581100464";
querySRVTime = "0.02561002969741821";
resolveDNSTime = "0.0296509861946106";
sessionID = 393665004;
timestampInfo =     (
            {
        name = SubSu;
    },
            {
        name = BePxT;
    },
            {
        name = AfPxT;
    },
            {
        name = BefEn;
    },
            {
        name = EmEnc;
    },
            {
        name = QueFr;
    },
            {
        name = SndFr;
    }
);
version = "211.3";
}
```

After this request the connnection stopped, I have tried send NTP request but it doesn't work.

So, I want to know What I need to do next or how to send the NTP request?

Thank you.